# oscommerce echo osc_link_object(osc_href_link problem

Tags: oscommerce

In oscommerce, I have set the DIR_WS_IMAGES from the config.php to be an external url so that the site loads the images from a static cookie-less subdomain.

The images work fine except the pop-us.

The pop-up scritp `echo osc_link_object(osc_href_link(DIR_WS_IMAGES.` will give the following url http://www.example.com/http://subdomain.example.com/products/originals/image.jpg which will not function as its calling main url plus the DIR_WS_IMAGES url.

How can I amend the script to just call subdomain.excample.com

Thanks for any help.

Regs Fabian

This is the code that is giving a double url [http://www.example.com/http://subdomain.example.com] that needs to be corrected to output just the [http://subdomian.example.com]

```
<?php 

    $group_id = $osC_Image->getID('originals');

    echo osc_link_object(osc_href_link(DIR_WS_IMAGES.'products/'.$osC_Image->getCode($group_id).'/'.$osC_Product->getImage(),null,'AUTO',false), $osC_Image->show($osC_Product->getImage(), $osC_Product->getTitle(), null, 'product_info'), 'target="_blank" rel=""');?>
```

Appreciate all the help.

Regs Fab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to correct the problem by simply doing

```
osc_link_object($link = DIR_WS_IMAGES.('products/'....
```

instead of

```
echo osc_link_object(osc_href_link(DIR_WS_IMAGES.'products/'....
```

Thanks to all does that offered help.

With best regards

Fabian

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and easiest thing to do (and won't look so out of place in osCommerce's code) is to do a `preg_replace()`.

```
echo str_replace('/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\//', '', osc_link_object(osc_href_link(DIR_WS_IMAGES.'whatever.jpg')));
```

Even better, dig out the global constant from `includes/config.php` and concatenate it in the regex - be sure to use `preg_quote(SITE_BASE, '/')` (assuming `SITE_BASE` is it, can't think of it right now off the top of my head).

Comment: Hi Alex, would there be something simpler, which would be echo the subdomain directly without having the script calling the main url and then removing it.

Comment: @Fabian Borg: Probably, just can't think of one right now (don't have the osCommerce code in front of me).

Comment: Thanks Alex, would appreciate any help ;)

Comment: HI Alex, had you the time to go through the code... Regs Fab ;)

Comment: @Fabian Borg Nope, I'm having some time off work and don't want to look at osCommerce code!

Answer (score 0):

May be this post can help you a bit. 
http://developerblog.e-cart-solutions.com/2010/10/product-images-images-from-remote-locations/
You can simply restort to replacing the domainname by the sudomain name if the paths are no different using a simple str_replace.

Shiva

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks for your input, this is the whole code that is calling the double url problem <?php 

        $group_id = $osC_Image->getID('originals');

        echo osc_link_object(osc_href_link(DIR_WS_IMAGES.'products/'.$osC_Image->getCode($group_id).'/'.$osC_Product->getImage(),null,'AUTO',false), $osC_Image->show($osC_Product->getImage(), $osC_Product->getTitle(), null, 'product_info'), 'target="_blank" rel=""');?>

Comment: Hi Shiva, the excersie I have done to move the image folder into a subdomain is not to slow the main site just as your article, since my images are over 1000 pixles wide. Unfortunately I have the double url problem which hopefully your good selves could help me with it. Cheers Fab

Comment: can you tell me what code you have in the class ? people can help you better if you could show that.

Comment: Hi Shiva, the whole code is up above in my question. Is there something else that I have to include. Please Guide me.